# MaskFormatter deixando espaço vazio

Tags: java, swing, formatação

No meu projeto, eu tenho um campo idade, onde quero receber no máximo 3 número, por isso fiz isso :

```
mskIdade = new MaskFormatter("###");
```

até ai tudo bem, porém acontece que toda vez que digito um número com menos de 3 caracteres, o `mskIdade` preenche os campos restantes com espaços vazios (`" "`). Tenho quase certeza que isso ocorre porque os  `###` **obrigam** o campo a ficar com três caracteres. Como eu consigo não obrigar que o campo tenha 3 caracteres e que o mesmo aceite **apenas** números ?

Comment: Você não quis deixar a pergunta de OOP? Eu estava respondendo

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você pode usar o [**trim()**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim()) em sua String, para remover espaços vazios a esquerda e a direita do valor:

```
String str = formattedTextField.getText().trim();
```

---

Outra maneira, talvez seja até melhor por te dar mais controle do que é digitado, é usando a classe [**PlainDocument**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/PlainDocument.html). Com ela, você não só controla a quantidade de caracteres que é digitado, como também se quer apenas números:

```
class JTextFieldLimit extends PlainDocument {

    private int limit;

    JTextFieldLimit(int limit) {
        super();
        this.limit = limit;
    }

    @Override
    public void insertString(int offset, String str, AttributeSet attr) throws BadLocationException {
        if (str == null) {
            return;
        }

        if ((getLength() + str.length()) <= limit) {

            super.insertString(offset, str.replaceAll("\\D++", ""), attr);
        }
    }
}
```

Depois é só aplicar a qualquer `JTextfield`:

```
    JTextFieldLimit limitDocument = new JTextFieldLimit(3);
    seuTextField.setDocument(limitDocument);
```

A assinatura do método `insertString` recebe três parâmetros:

- `int offset` = indica em qual índice da string atual do campo, a nova será adicionada;
- `String str` = é a nova string que será adicionada(dígitos, no seu caso);
- `AttributeSet attr` = são atributos da string(como tipo, tamanho e estilo de fonte, etc...), neste caso, não nos fez diferença.

No `str.replaceAll("\\D++", "")`, estou passando uma [**Expressão Regular**](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Express%C3%A3o_regular) que irá remover quaisquer caracteres passados na string que não sejam dígitos.

Lembrando que o construtor da classe `JTextFieldLimit` recebe o limite de caracteres que seu campo poderá ter, e esta classe pode ser usada em qualquer campo de de texto.

> **Obs.:** Com a classe apresentada acima, você não precisar utilizar nem
>   `MaskFormatter` e nem `JTextFormatterField`.

**Referências:**

[Limit JTextField input to a maximum length(java2s)](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/LimitJTextFieldinputtoamaximumlength.htm)

[How to implement in Java ( JTextField class ) to allow entering only digits?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5663094/5524514)

[Limitando o número de caracteres em um JTextField](http://www.botecodigital.info/java/limitando-o-numero-de-caracteres-em-um-jtextfield/)

Comment: Boa ! Fiquei com uma pequena dúvida : Oque seriam os elementos `int offset` e `AttributeSet attr` ? São parâmetros que já vem carregados quando vc carrega o método, ou foi vc que colocou eles ali ?

Comment: @DanielSantos `offset` é a posição atual do cursor onde a string será inserida. [Olhando esta imagem do doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/text/doc-files/Document-coord.gif)  fica mais fácil entender. `AttributeSet` são características da string que será adicionada(como fonte, tamanho, etc...).

Answer (score 1):

Fiz dois métodos que podem ajudar você com esse problema:

Verificar se existem apenas números em uma String.

```
public static boolean apenasNumeros(String text){
    return text.matches("[0-9]+");
}
```

Retornar apenas os números de uma String.

```
public static String tirarTudoExcetoDigitos( String text) {
       if (text == null || text.length() == 0) {
           return "";
       }
       return text.replaceAll("\\D+", "");
    }
```

Pequeno exemplo:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String test1 = "12345";
    System.out.println("Teste 1:");
    System.out.println("Apenas Números? " + apenasNumeros(test1));
    System.out.println("Apenas Números!! " + tirarTudoExcetoDigitos(test1));
    String test2 = "123A5";
    System.out.println("Teste 2:");
    System.out.println("Apenas Números? " + apenasNumeros(test2));
    System.out.println("Apenas Números!! " + tirarTudoExcetoDigitos(test2));
}
```

Resultado:

```
Teste 1:
Apenas Números? true
Apenas Números!! 12345
Teste 2:
Apenas Números? false
Apenas Números!! 1235
```

Comment: Só tem um problema nessa resposta: como vai aplicar esse método ao campo? Apesar de filtrar corretamente, o campo vai continuar permitindo digitar qualquer coisa. A finalidade do maskformatter(e do plaindocument) é nem deixar o usuário digitar o que não pode, ao invés de ter que filtrar depois que ele digitar.