# JFormattedTextField não está aceitando nenhum caractere

Tags: java, swing, formatação

Tenho uma janela onde temos um `JFomattedTextField` chamado `txtQuantia`, apliquei uma máscara a ele chamado `mskQuantia`, e settei os caracteres válidos, no caso, 0-9, porém esse campo não está aceitando nenhum caractere ... O que pode ser ?

```
MaskFormatter mskQuantia = new MaskFormatter();
mskQuantia.setValidCharacters("0123456789");

JFormattedTextField txtQuantia = new JFormattedTextField(mskQuantia);
```

Lembrando que não precisei colocar um `try`/`catch` para instanciar a máscara ...

Comment: Porque você não aplicou nenhuma máscara.

Comment: É porque de fato, não quero aplicar máscara para limitar os dígitos (por exemplo `###`), quero apenas que o campo aceite números, sem limites ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Da forma como você está fazendo, não está sendo aplicada nenhuma mascara no campo. Está apenas iniciando a variável `mskQuantia`, porém sem nenhuma máscara válida.

O método [`setValidCharacters()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/text/MaskFormatter.html#setValidCharacters-java.lang.String-) apenas filtra o que você quer que seja aceito na máscara aplicada no campo, daí voltamos ao parágrafo anterior, você não está aplicando nenhuma máscara, apesar de estar "instalando" o `MaskFormatter` vazio no campo.

Esta resposta sobre [como fazer essa restrição em JTextField](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/133841/28595) talvez seja a opção mais recomendada para o caso que você quer, já que não há tanto compromisso com máscara ou formatação do que deve ser digitado.

Basta adaptar o código, removendo a limitação de quantidade máxima de caracteres:

```
import javax.swing.text.PlainDocument;

class JTextFieldFilter extends PlainDocument {

    JTextFieldLimit() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void insertString(int offset, String str, AttributeSet attr) throws BadLocationException {
        if (str == null) {
            return;
        }
        super.insertString(offset, str.replaceAll("\\D++", ""), attr);
    }
}
```

O Código acima deverá ser aplicado ao `JTextField` da seguinte maneira:

```
seuJTextField.setDocument(new JTextFieldFilter());
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode adicionar um evento keytyped.

```
  private void campoSomenteNumero(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
   String num = "0123456789";
        if (!num.contains(evt.getKeyChar() + "") {
            evt.consume();
        }
     }
```

Algo parecido com isso, nem precisa ser campo formatado.

Comment: Para fazer filtro em campos de texto, não é recomendado usar eventos de teclas como este, além de ser mais custoso pra aplicação, não vai filtrar algo colado através de um `control` + `V`. O recomendado e correto é usar plainDocument ou até mesmo DocumentFilter.

Comment: Tem como anular o 'control' + 'V', lembro de ter feito isso ano passado, usando o mesmo método de captura de eventos.

Comment: Ai você estará adicionando restrição desnecessária ao campo, sendo que apenas  com o plaindocument. essa filtragem já é feita, independente se o conteudo foi digitado ou colado. Complicar algo que pode ser simples é bobeira.