# JTextField que aceite apenas duas letras

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

Como faço para que, em um `JTextField`, eu consiga apenas digitar duas letras do teclado e não usar mais nenhuma outra letra, número ou caractere? Por exemplo: em um campo eu só quero ele aceite ou a letra T ou a Letra F (maiúsculas).

Comment: Cara tou perguntando como se faz, porque eu não sei fazer

Answer (score 3):

Eventos de `KeyListener` apenas detectam, mas não impedem de ser digitado o texto dentro do campo, e utilizar `KeyListener` pra filtrar caracteres e remove-los do campo não é uma boa prática, devido ao baixo nível que esses métodos trabalham para monitorar ações do teclado.

Sem contar que, se copiar e colar(<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> e <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>) um texto qualquer que possua as duas letras ou não, o `KeyListener` não vai identificar.

O ideal é utilizar [`PlainDocument`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/PlainDocument.html) ou [`DocumentFilter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/DocumentFilter.html), que não dependem exclusivamente de ações do teclado como `keyPress` e monitoram diretamente a string digitada no campo.

No [exemplo da duplicata](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/133841/28595), além de permitir limitar a quantidade de caracteres, está filtrando apenas números, então, para permitir apenas duas letras exclusivas, basta alterar a regex. Seguindo o exemplo das letras dadas, ficaria assim:

```
super.insertString(offset, str.replaceAll("([^FT])", ""), attr);
```

Estou permitindo que seja digitado apenas as letras mencionadas em suas versões em caixa alta, não permitindo que quaisquer outros caracteres, mesmo que se tente colar do clipboard.

Fiz um exemplo executável que se encontra [**no github**](https://github.com/diegofelipem/stackoverflow/blob/master/src/swing/examples3/JTextFieldFilterTest.java), basta compilar e executar.

Comment: Agora sim, uma real ajuda!

Comment: @PauloH.Hartmann no site não se ajuda somente com respostas, comentários apontando erros em respostas também é colaborar com conteúdo. Basta que o autor esteja disposto a aceitar a crítica e corrigir o problema. Se eu tiver que responder tudo que comento que pode ter erros aqui, eu teria mais de 10.000 respostas no site, mas meu objetivo é ajudar a melhorar o conteúdo do site, **seja ele de minha autoria ou não**.

Comment: Com certeza, nessa situação concordo contigo. Talvez tenhamos pontos de vista diferentes sobre colaborar.

Comment: Minha pergunta não tem nada a ver com a sitada de MaskFormatter, se observar bem o que escrevi, não tem nada a ver. Ate o titulo é diferente

Comment: Mas já concegui resolver isso.. e Obrigado

Comment: @WilliamsBarriquero tem a ver sim, tanto q utilizei a mesma solução de lá nessa resposta, e ela faz exatamente o que vc pediu. Se tivesse lido direito a minha resposta, teria notado a semelhança ;)