# Setas não se movem em campo de texto com regex

Tags: java, regex, swing

Tenho a seguinte código com uma expressão regular dentro de um método `Keyreleased`, que permite somente alguns caracteres ser digitados pelo usuário em um campo de texto:

```
String text = input.getText();
text = text.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z&\\|!]", "");
input.setText(text.toUpper());
```

Ao tentar pressionar as teclas de setas como <kbd><-</kbd>(esquerda) ou (direita) <kbd>-></kbd>, a expressão regular não deixa eu voltar na string para editar algo, o Regex não permite.

Exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O cursor nesse momento está a frente de C, mas não consigo voltar o cursor de forma que fique na frente de B ou A.

Alguém saberia me dizer como resolver esse problema?

Comment: E o código pra testar?

Comment: Normalmente esse `text.replaceAll` não é usado para tratar eventos de chave pressionada. Onde está o resto do código?

Comment: Eu apliquei essa mesma query aqui e não deu o problema. Se você não fornecer um **[mcve]** fica complicado te ajudar. Repito: **o problema em nada tem a ver com o replaceAll ou com a regex**, é outro pedaço do código que você não está informando.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Conforme mencionei nos comentários mas nunca é demais repetir, **o problema em nada tem a ver com o** `replaceAll` **ou com a regex**, e sim com o listener que você está usando.

O evento `KeyReleased` é disparado toda vez que uma tecla é liberada após ser pressionada. Setas também são teclas, então cada vez que você apertar alguma, o evento será disparado.

Como você não forneceu um trecho relevante para análise, vou supor que seu evento esteja semelhante ao abaixo:

```
@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    JTextComponent input = ((JTextComponent) e.getSource());
    String text = input.getText();
    text = text.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z&\\|!]", "");
    input.setText(text.toUpperCase());
}
```

Perceba que cada vez que uma tecla for pressionada no campo de texto, toda esta rotina irá ocorrer. E quando você pressionar uma tecla de direção(ou setas), todo o texto do campo será filtrado pela regex e depois reaplicado no campo, e isso fará com que o `Caret` padrão(aquele cursor de texto que aparece no campo),[se mova para o final da nova sentença aplicada](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/text/DefaultCaret.html).

Não é recomendado que se use eventos de teclado para filtrar strings em campos de textos, haja visto que campos de textos possuem outro meio adequado para isso, que é através das classes derivadas de [`Document`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/text/Document.html) .

[**Nesta resposta**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/133841/28595) há um exemplo de uso da classe [`PlainDocument`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/text/PlainDocument.html), adaptando para sua situação, seria algo como abaixo:

```
input.setDocument(new PlainDocument() {
    @Override
    public void insertString(int offs, String str, AttributeSet a) throws BadLocationException {
        if (str == null) {
            return;
        }
        super.insertString(offs, str.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z&\\|!]", "").toUpperCase(), a);
    }
});
```

Funcionando:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na resposta que linkei há mais detalhes sobre esta classe.